# Reading word into an array [ruby]

Tags: ruby, while-loop, user-input

Trying to create a ceaser cipher in Ruby.
The problem I'm facing is that when the program reaches the while loop, it only performs the desired operation on the very last letter of the inputted word. Before I delve further into what I've tried, please find  the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby


#print 65.chr  ASCII code for A
#print 97.chr  ASCII code for a

a = 0
b = 97
d = []
e = 0

# Just to print the alphabet alongside the ASCII value 
# (For sanity checking)

while a <= 25
  print b.chr + " "
  print b.to_s + "\n"
  a = a + 1
  b = b + 1
end

puts "\n Please enter a word to translate"
word = gets.strip

# The desired effect is to move the letter along by key value

puts "Please enter a key"
k = gets.chomp.to_i

# In its current state, what happens is only the last char
# is moved along by the key value. 

while e <= word.length
  word.each_byte do |c|
    d[e] = c + k
  end
  e = e + 1
end


puts d
```

I'm thinking that the problem lies with the logic for the while loop. The way I am going to attack this is by reading the pre-converted word into an array, as opposed to using the .each_byte object.

I don't know how to do that and the guides/questions I've found don't quite answer the question. If anyone knows how to do this, or knows a better way of solving this- I'd be much appreciative.

Comment: If a user enters a word of 'abc' and a key of 2, do you want the system to output 'cde'?

Comment: That's right yes

Comment: To do a Caesar cipher, you also have to figure out a way to wrap around again, for example to have `z` come back `b` if there's a key of `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need the last while loop

```
  word.each_byte do |c|
    d[e] = c + k
    e = e + 1
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Something a bit more verbose:

```
alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
new_word = ''

puts "\n Please enter a word to translate"
word = gets.strip

puts "Please enter a key"
k = gets.chomp.to_i

word.split('').each_with_index do |letter, index|
  alphabet_index = alphabet.index(letter)
  new_index = alphabet_index + key
  new_word[index] = alphabet[new_index]
end

puts "Your translated word is #{new_word}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Caesar cipher is a simple shift cipher

```
word.each_byte do |c| 
  p c + k 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working, thanks for all the help... Code for anyone interested:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

#print 65.chr  A
#print 97.chr  a

a = 0
b = 65
y = 97
d = []
e = 0

while a <= 25
  print y.chr + " = " + y.to_s + " "
  print b.chr + " = " + b.to_s + " " + "\n"
  a = a + 1
  b =  b + 1
  y = y + 1
end


puts "\n Please enter a word to translate"
word = gets.strip

puts "Please enter a key"
k = gets.chomp.to_i

word.each_byte do |c|
  d[e] = c + k
  e = e + 1
end

print "\n"

a = 0
arlen = d.count


while a != arlen
  print d[a].chr
  a = a + 1
end
print k
```